# How to put two elements in a comprehension list in haskell

Tags: haskell

I've been looking some time now and I couldn't find how to do this. Suppose I have two lists, I want to return a new list that is the same as the result of `zip` but without the duples, e.g., given `[1,2,3]` and `[4,5,6]` the result would be `[1,4,2,5,3,6]`. I would do it like (suppossing the compiler don't generate an error):

```
 myFunc xs ys = [x,y|(x,y) <- zip xs ys]
```

PS: Have to do it with list comprehension.

Could you give some thoughts about it?

Comment: `[ z | (x,y) <- zip xs ys, z <- [x,y] ]`

Comment: What about `concat [[x,y] | (x,y) <- zip xs ys]`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem The result should be a flat list.

Comment: @dcg: with `concat` the result **is** a flat list.

Comment: @Ale That worked. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry @WillemVanOnsem I didn't see the `concat`, it works as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want `-XParallelListComp` which is a syntactic sugar for zip. Other than that sugar the solution matches what has already been suggested:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ParallelListComp #-}

xs = [1..3]
ys = [4..6]
ls = concat [ [x,y] | x <- xs | y <- ys ]
```

With a result of:

```
*Main> ls
[1,4,2,5,3,6]
```

Comment: Are there any uses of `-XParallelListComp` in the wild? I've heard about it before, but I never understood the motivation behind why it was introduced in the first place...

Comment: Sure, just google for `site:hackage.haskell.org LANGUAGE ParallelListComp`.  Manifolds, kansas lava, many many pages of packages.  As for where it came from? Cryptol had this feature first, I think.  It's handy therefore it is.

Comment: @Alec I don't think I ever used them, but I still classify them in the "nice to have" bucket, since they are fairly simple to understand. Instead, I find SQL-like comprehensions quite alien.

Answer (score 2):

This can also be conveniently done without extensions:

```
myFunc xs ys = [x | pairs <- transpose [xs, ys], x <- pairs]
```

This doesn't throw away elements as Thomas M. DuBuisson's answer does; e.g. `myFunc [] [1]` will be `[1]`, not `[]`. Whether that's desirable or not depends on your needs, of course.

But even simpler is not to use list comprehensions at all, so that you don't need to name the intermediary `pairs`.

```
myFunc xs ys = concat (transpose [xs, ys])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func a b = concat (map ( \(x,y) -> [x,y] ) (zip a b))
```

Do you mean something like this ?

Comment: `foldr (++) []` is a strange function to write, since it is equivalent to `concat` or `join`.

Comment: That is right, I kinda forgot that was a built-in function. I'm editing the answer.